# I am trying to insert values into a MySQL database but an error states duplicate entry

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Here is my code. I encounter an error and I am new to PHP. I am doing a project where I need to grab the enter values and show in an HTML table. Can you please recommend me a good way to solve this error.

> Error: INSERT INTO levels (level, maxTotal,minTotal,steps) VALUES ('one', 'eight', 'two','three')
>   Duplicate entry 'one' for key 'level'
>   Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in H:\webdev3\www\try2\dashBoard.php on line 7
>   0 results

```
{
    public $host;
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $dab;
    public $conn;

    public function dbConnect()
    {
        $this->conn = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->username, $this->password);

        if (!$this->conn) {
            die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        } else {
            //echo "Connected successfully to server";
        }

        $db_selected = mysqli_select_db($this->conn, $this->dab);

        if (!$db_selected) {
            // if the given database doesn't exists
            // creates new database with that name
            $db_sql = 'CREATE DATABASE userLogin';

            // verify the database is created
            if (mysqli_query($this->conn, $db_sql)) {
                echo "Database userlogin already exists or created successfully\n";
            } else {
                echo 'Error creating database: ' . mysqli_error() . "\n";
            }
        }

        // creating tables
        $table_sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (" . "uid INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT," . "username VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE," . "password VARCHAR(50)," . "name VARCHAR(100)," . "email VARCHAR(70) UNIQUE); ";
        $table_sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS levels (" . "uid INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT," . "level VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE," . "maxTotal VARCHAR(50)," . "minTotal VARCHAR(100)," . "steps VARCHAR(70) UNIQUE); ";

        $sql = "INSERT INTO levels (level, maxTotal,minTotal,steps) VALUES ('one', 'eight', 'two','three')";
        // verify the table is created
        if (mysqli_query($this->conn, $sql)) {
            echo "New record created successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($this->conn);
        }
        if (mysqli_query($this->conn, $table_sql)) {
            // echo "Table: users already exists or created successfully\n";
        } else {
            echo 'Error creating table: ' . mysqli_error($table_sql) . "\n";
        }

    }
}

$obj = new dbConfig();

$obj->host     = 'localhost';
$obj->username = 'root';
$obj->password = '';
$obj->dab      = 'user';
$obj->dbConnect();
```

Comment: Does the level table already present with data, perhaps?  Your create table query does have 'if not exists'.

Comment: @PaulT. its not present with data atm,  i just added custom values to check whether i can query data to show in the html table.

Comment: Can you post the results of this query: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM userLogin.levels`

Comment: Also, could you be possibly working with two databases? (maybe).  When the object is created, the 'dab' name is `user`. But then in the code if the select_db fails, then the create DB uses `userLogin` as the DB name.

Answer (score 0):

If the error you're getting is the problem you can solve it either by removing "UNIQUE" when you create the table, or by changing "INSERT INTO..." to "INSERT IGNORE INTO..." or by not trying to insert a duplicate value into a unique field.

If you're trying to handle such the error if a user were to submit a problem, you might nest the insert call into a try/catch statement, where you can handle the error in a graceful way.

I don't know enough about your specific application or requirements to know what you really want. If you elaborate a little more about the desired outcome I'm sure I could give you a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have a unique key and there's data clearly already in that table. I notice your code attempts to add data to the table before it attempts to create it, so you should probably fix that as well. And, thanks to you overwriting the table create statement, there's no way the users table could ever be created.

My advice: redo the above to sequentially and properly handle the various cases where the DB or the tables don't exist, or the data isn't in them. At the most basic level, you can do an CREATE IF NOT EXISTS and INSERT IGNORE unconditionally. It would certainly simplify your code somewhat.

Comment: Thank you Sir! yes i realize that i have repeated same value which having a unique value.